# Add class when model value is changed

Tags: angularjs

I have 2 datepickers and by default I am setting today's date in **Check In Date** and tomorrow's date in **Check Out Date** using `ng-model`.

The model value is changed when another dates are selected through the datepicker.

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <label class="control-label" for="date">Check In Date</label>
    <input class="form-control" id="date" name="date" value="{{date | date: 'yyyy-MM-dd'}}" ng-model="checkinDate" type="text"/>
</div>

<div class="col-md-4"> 
    <label class="control-label" for="date1">Check Out Date</label>
    <input class="form-control" id="date1" name="date" value="{{date1 | date: 'yyyy-MM-dd'}}" ng-model="checkoutDate" type="text"/>
</div>

<div class="col-md-4">
    <md-button class="md-raised" md-ripple-size="full" id="checkAvail" ng-click="checkAvail(roomdata.data)">CHECK AVAILABILITY</md-button>
</div>
```

I want to add a class `'shake'` in my md-button when my `ng-model="checkoutDate"` is changed.

How do I use `ng-class` for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best bet is to use `ng-class` and have your condition set in there. Something like:

```
ng-class="{'shake': myModel == true}"
```

Comment: Here's a pen with two nice examples for using ng-class: https://codepen.io/hbuchel/pen/Hewog

Comment: Ok I did something like this and it worked `ng-class="{'shake': checkoutDate != checkoutDate1}"`

Answer (score 1):

You give the model name `checkoutDate` in the class expression,

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <md-button class="md-raised" md-ripple-size="full" id="checkAvail" ng-click="checkAvail(roomdata.data)" ng-class="{shake: checkoutDate}">CHECK AVAILABILITY</md-button>
</div>
```

So, when ever you select a value in `checkoutDate` the class `shake` gets added.

Comment: checkoutDate is already set so this won't work. I did it with `ng-class="{'shake': checkoutDate != checkoutDate1}"`

Answer (score 1):

```
 <md-button class="badge" [ngClass]="{'md-raised': (status ==
 'NOT-CHANGED'), 'shake': (status == 'CHANGED')}" md-ripple-
  size="full" id="checkAvail" ng-click="checkAvail(roomdata.data)"> 
  Check Availability</md-button>
```

Here in code you can employ a change function to capture that checkout date has been selected and in that function change 'status' as 'CHANGED' this will, in turn inject the class you require to the button you have defined

```
 <input class="form-control" id="date1" name="date" value="{{date1 | 
 date: 'yyyy-MM-dd'}}" ng-model="checkoutDate" ng-    
 click="changeStatus()" type="text"/>
```

change status will contain converting status of variable from 'NOT-CHANGED' to 'CHANGED'

```
 changeStatus(){
     this.status = 'CHANGED';
 }
```

Do not forget to define status in the constructor. Hope this helps

Comment: This works but in this way the class is added when the input field is clicked and not when a date is selected.